# Cannot delete cookie from JS

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need to delete this cookie in firefox using JS

[image]

When I use this code, the cookie is not removed

```
document.cookie = "swSessionID=; path=/sw/selfservice/; domain=supportworkslab.sw.test; expires=Mon, 11 Dec 2017 05:41:47 GMT"
```

The only thing that I can think of is that the cookie is not secure, but my host is. Do I need to specify that secure is false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For latest browsers to honor cookie expiration date you need to set **Max-Age**. 
Expires accepts a date string whereas Max-Age takes seconds like Max-Age=31536000 which means it will expire after 1 year starting from the moment the browser received the cookie.
Expires is for old browsers like IE6, 7 & 8 and FF 3 and chrome early versions.